# Symfony Console Component - Tokens vs Arguments

Tags: symfony, console-application

I'm building a cli application with Symfony Console Component. I'm using several other libraries - Monolog among others. I use the logger to log information about the command being executed, exit statuses, etc.

I find that I cannot print or log input arguments that I pass to my command.

When I call `$inputArgs = $event->getInput();` in my event listener, I get an object of `Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput` class. This class provides a method to retrieve a value of an argument:

> getArgument(string $name) Returns the argument value for a given
>   argument name.

This method will always return an empty array since 'arguments' are in fact 'tokens'. Here is a screenshot from a debug window:

[image]

This seems very misleading. I need to get the values stored in `$tokens` and I do not want to resort to the global `$_SERVER` array.

Why are 'arguments' introduced by `addArgument()` tokens ? And how could I access them without resorting to `$_SERVER`?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still needs this. For me it was enough to cast the Input-Object into a string:

`$executedCommand = (string)$inputArgs;`

This gives me the command input.

[Github: __toString in ArgvInput.php](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/6.3/Input/ArgvInput.php#L354)